# Raiden National - How to use?

Tags: genshin-impact

The "Raiden National" or "Rational" team comp consists of Raiden Shogun, Xingqiu, Xiangling and Bennet

At face value, it is an overvape comp that is used a lot in the Spiral Abyss

I have tried using this comp myself and found it interesting only against ruin opponents who are kind of very vulnerable to reaction damage. My comp consists of C0 Raiden (80/90 - 4pc Emblem - The Catch), C6 Xingqiu (80/90 - 4pc Emblem - Sac sword), C3 Xiangling (80/90 - 4pc Emblem - Skyward Spine) and C5 Bennet (89/90 4pc Noblesse - Alley Flash)

I found that it struggles clearing fast against everything except Fatui and Ruin enemies (even so, the Perpetual Mechanical Array gives me trouble clearing it fast)

My rotation is Raiden skill -> Xingqiu skill - burst - skill -> Bennet burst - skill -> Xiangling burst - skill -> Raiden burst N1C until it expires -> Raiden skill to initiate another rotation

When Raiden's burst expires, the cooldown of Xingqiu's burst isn't ready yet so I have to just sit there on him, doing NAs and wait for burst before continuing the rotation

The problem I have is: non heavy enemies are projected left and right during Raiden's burst and I have to catch up to them, making me get out of Bennet's burst and lose his buff, cutting my damage by a half

I have heard of edge-baiting, but some enemies (like fungi) just take a while to come close to me, making me lose time

Is there an adjustment I should do to my rotation or do I just have to edge-bait better?

Comment: Although old, this question occurred to me today also, broader, in how the team works, but this question is lacking an anemo to group.

Comment: @Neon1024 you're not mixing it with the Hyper Raiden (Raiden/Kazuha/Sara/Bennet), are you?